# Safe handling of userspace pointers in a driver?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm writing an ioctl driver that needs to read and write data to userspace. For visualization, here's a typical argument that goes in a driver call:

```
typedef struct {
unsigned int* src;
unsigned int* dst;
unsigned int buffer_size;
unsigned int key[8];
} aes_data
```

I'm not very well-versed in how virtual memory works, but I think there's a risk here. The userspace process could have provided a pointer to memory it does not own. The provided buffer size could cause an overflow into the memory of some other process as well. How do I handle these userspace pointers responsibly in my driver?

Comment: Are you aware of `copy_to_user` and `copy_from_user` kernel's functions? If not, it is time to learn about them. Because accessing (read/write) user memory should be performed only with given functions (and some variations of them).

Comment: I used them, but I wasn't aware that that's all it takes. Writing wherever the user tells me to, with no explicit checking on my part seemed pretty reckless :)

Comment: `copy_to_user` and  `copy_from_user` do basic checks and they could failed to finish copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I handle these userspace pointers responsibly in my driver?

You don't, simply because there are no ways to check if the pointers points to anything valid. It is up to the user of the ioctl() to provide proper parameters. If they fail to do that, then tough luck for them.